# neo4j scheme vs bolt scheme -- what is the difference, when should I use one over the other

Tags: neo4j

I am setting up a neo4j aura database

I have a choice of two schemes:

- `neo4j+s://`
- `bolt+s://`

What are the similarities?

- They both seem to have secured variations, using "encryption and full certificate checks against the system’s local CA store."
- They both seem to support a `ssc` (self signed certificate) variation

What are the differences?

- [This page mentions `neo4j` scheme has "routing" whereas `bolt` does not](https://neo4j.com/docs/upgrade-migration-guide/current/version-4/migration/drivers/new-uri-schemes/)

  - [But this page](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/how-neo4j-browser-bolt-routing/) mentions the `bolt+routing` scheme
  - How is "routing" relevant anyway, is routing only applicable when we talk about "clusters" of neo4j nodes vs "single instance" configurations (distributed among many servers, vs one server)?
- The [pages](https://docs.graphenedb.com/docs/connecting-to-your-database#section-connect-using-bolt-binary-protocol) I can find on `bolt` say it is a "binary protocol over persistent TCP" suggesting it is "high-performance", is it better than neo4j scheme then?

  - Other [pages](https://neo4j.com/docs/bolt/current/bolt/) say bolt can also operate over WebSocket connection
- [Some pages suggest](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-python-driver#connection-settings-breaking-change-4x) "The `neo4j://` scheme **replaces `bolt+routing://`** and can be used for both clustered and single-instance configurations..."

[image: connecting to an instance of neo4j hosted Aura, the user has the choice between neo4j+s and bolt+s schemes]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `bolt+routing` is the ancestor of the `neo4j` scheme, in the 3.x version of Neo4j (where the `+s` and `+ssc` were specified through explicit configuration, not through the scheme)
- `neo4j`, `neo4j+s`, `neo4j+ssc` imply (client-side) routing, the driver will regularly fetch routing information (initially from the target server) and route further queries appropriately
- `bolt`, `bolt+s`, `bolt+ssc` means direct connection to the target server

Before Neo4j 4, single server instances did NOT support the `neo4j` scheme, they would fail returning routing information.
That is not true anymore, which is why using the `neo4j` scheme (or its variants thereof) is usually a good default since both single instances and clusters support it.

Using the `bolt` scheme in a highly dynamic cluster environment is a BAD idea. The cluster topology can change pretty quickly.
For instance, the initially targeted server may change from a leader to a follower role. When that happens, the server then starts to fail serving writes.

The `neo4j` scheme (or its variants) avoids this problem since the driver will keep an up-to-date view of the cluster topology and route queries accordingly.

All official drivers supports Bolt over raw TCP.
The JavaScript driver also supports Bolt over Websocket.
The Go driver also supports Bolt over Unix sockets.

Answer (score 1):

`neo4j://` replaced `bolt+routing://`, the former being added in the Neo4j 4.x time range, and the latter being the prior scheme.

`bolt://` is a direct connection between client and server, resulting in all requested being sent directly to said server. Think of this as a point to point connection between the client and server. The protocol is binary.

`neo4j://` can make use of client side routing, where as `bolt://` cannot. This client side routing is only applicable to clusters, and requires server side routing to be disabled.

https://neo4j.com/docs/bolt/current/driver-api/#uri-schemes

https://neo4j.com/docs/bolt/current/driver-api/#_clusters_and_multiple_databases

When a client makes a connection to the dbms with `neo4j://` it will request a routing table. This will contain information on who is the leader/ writer and who are followers/ readers (note the terminology has changed from leader to writer and followers to readers in Neo4j 5).

With the routing table now present on the client, the client can make *intelligent* decisions on where to send a query based on the server's role (writer vs reader) and the type of transaction (write vs read). This is explained on the client drivers documentation, here is the Java

https://neo4j.com/docs/java-manual/current/session-api/#java-driver-simple-transaction-fn

> Transaction functions can be called as either read or write operations. This choice will route the transaction to an appropriate server within a clustered environment. If you are operating in a single instance environment, this routing has no impact. It does give you flexibility if you choose to adopt a clustered environment later on.

Once the client has made a decision on where to send the query, the *routed* `neo4j://` connection is sending data over `Packstream+bolt` under the hood sent to and received from a (usually TCP) connection to the target.

As stated above, this is only applicable to clusters. But, typically a `neo4j://` scheme should be used for the vast majority of cases, even if you are only planning on a single server at this point in time.

There is the exception of [server side routing](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/clustering/setup/routing/#clustering-routing), which can enforce that clients make a point to point connection by only sending a routing table with one entry containing itself. This forces the client to send all queries to the server it initially connected to. With server side routing it doesn't matter which scheme is used, it will always be a point to point connection